# QGraphicsView - Qt5 - Не срабатывает событие mouseMoveEvent?

Tags: qt, qt5

Работаю с Qt. Центральный виджет:
.h file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <gameboard.h>
#include <QMainWindow>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    GameBoard* gb;
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Конструктор:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    gb=new GameBoard(this);

}
```

Класс GameBoard :

.h file :

```
class GameBoard : public QGraphicsView
{
friend class MainWindow;
public:
    GameBoard(QWidget *parent);
private:
 QVBoxLayout* mainLayout;
 QGraphicsView* gameBoard;
 QGraphicsScene* scene;
protected:
   void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};
```

.cpp :

```
GameBoard::GameBoard(QWidget *parent)
{
    gameBoard = new QGraphicsView();
    mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    gameBoard->setParent(parent);
    gameBoard->setMinimumSize(parent->width(),parent->height());
    gameBoard->viewport()->setMouseTracking(true);

    scene=new QGraphicsScene();
    QPen pen;
    QColor black(0,0,0);
    pen.setColor(black);
    scene->addEllipse(0, 0, 10,10, pen, QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));
    gameBoard->setScene(scene);
}
void GameBoard::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug()<<event->pos().x();
}
```

В качестве примера использовал:

https://pro-prof.com/forums/topic/qgraphicsscene-drawing

Решил перепроверить, вот, на английском SO - тот же способ, отмечен как решение:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817538/how-to-use-mouse-move-event-for-qgraphicsscene

UPD:  Забыл уточнить, что событие не срабатывает даже с зажатой ЛКМ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию событие о передвижении мыши не отслеживается и GameBoard::mouseMoveEvent сработает только при передвижении с нажатой кнопкой мыши. Если вы делаете рисовалку, возможно вам большего и не надо. Но если кровь из носа требуется, то примерно так:

```
GameBoard::GameBoard(QWidget *parent)
{
    ...
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
    this->centralWidget()->setMouseTracking(true);
    // хотя в вашем случае подозреваю что надо   gameBoard->setMouseTracking(true);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sergey Tatarincev, спасибо за ответ. Проблем в том, что даже с зажатой ЛКМ - событие не срабатывает.
В GB - заменил `gameBoard->viewport()->setMouseTracking(true);`
на:

 `this->setMouseTracking(true);
gameBoard->setMouseTracking(true);`

добавил в .cpp - MainWindow:

`this->centralWidget()->setMouseTracking(true);`

-все равно, событие не срабатывает.

Comment: выложите куда-нибудь полностью проект (github или типа того). попробую помочь. по вашим кускам к сожалению всего не исправить. Я сразу не заметил, но ваш самописный класс не наследует даже QObject не говоря уже о QWidget

Comment: Sergey Tatarincev,

https://github.com/BadCatsss/GraphicsViewDemo 

Спасибо.

Comment: https://github.com/tatarintsevsv/test Это из вашего кода. Но зачем такой велосипед не вполне понятно. Логичнее все это реализовать в самом MainWindow (выкинуть лишний класс и половину ненужного кода), тем более что оно все равно будет крутиться в одном потоке с общим эвентлупом.